# How do I fix a label on the chart even when zooming in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

is there any way to fix a label on the right side of the chart, no matter how much I zoom it or move the chart?

thanks!!!

Elan

Comment: The question is vague. It's certainly easy to dock a label to the right side of the last bar in  a chart. As it is to dock the label to the right of the screen. Same for up, down and left in any context. But you cannot do that easily for arbitrary positionning on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do it with labels however tables can be done, looks a lot better also.